# (jquery/javascript) How would I make click function work after key event

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyevent

I have two divs with id "display" and "display2" where i put the results of my functions.

What the code below does is print `one two three four` in a row with a span starting around `one` and when you press the left and right keys, it removes the span on the previous item and puts a span on the next item.

I also have a click function at the very bottom that, when span is clicked, display2 will display a number that should count up.

The problem is:

When screen loads, and no keys are pressed, clicking on spans, for example, `<span>one</span>` will increase the number count in display 2 normally.

Once I press the left and right keys, and let's say the span is on `<span>three</span>`, if I click try clicking `<span>three</span>`, the counter in #display2 doesn't do anything. Why is this and how can I fix it?

```
   var arr1 = ["one ", "two ", "three ", "four "];
    var arr2 = ["<span>one </span>", "two ", "three ", "four "];
    var counter = 0;

function count(){
  if (counter>0 && event.keyCode==37){
    counter--;
  }
  else if (counter<3 &&event.keyCode==39){
     counter++;
           }
}

function spaN() {
  arr2[counter] = '<span>' + arr1[counter] + '</span>';
    if (event.keyCode==37){
   arr2[counter+1] = arr1[counter+1];
  }
  else if (event.keyCode==39){
   arr2[counter-1] = arr1[counter-1];  
           }
}

$(document).keydown(function(event){
switch(event.keyCode){
  case 37:
    count();
    spaN();
    $('#display').html(arr2);
    break;
  case 39:
    count();
    spaN();
    $('#display').html(arr2);    
    break;
       }
});

$('#display').html(arr2);

var k = 0;
$('span').click(function(){
k++;
 $('#display2').html(k);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is probably causing the issue: `$('span').click(function(){....`

That selector will get you all the Current span tags on the page.
Once you update the display, the spans inside it, aren't the same spans anymore as the event was bound to.
So you'll need to delegate the event to the document, the body, or the displays, so that any new spans inserted in the displays, also can use the click handler.
The alternative would be to manually reassign the click handler every time you set the .html() of the displays, but that would be inefficient.

Try something like this:

```
$('body').on('click', 'span', function() {
    k++;
    $('#display2').html(k);
});
```

Basically, you tell the body, to run that function once any span is clicked. THis will be checked at runtime, so it will apply to any future spans created, as long as the body tag itsself doesn't get replaced.